# Concurrently merging many sorted arrays

Tags: java, arrays, concurrency, merge

I am currently working on a program to sort strings concurrently. My program takes in a file, reads each line of the file into an array, and splits the array of strings into smaller arrays of strings. The program then starts up one thread for each of the smaller arrays, and quicksorts them. Once every thread has finished sorting its array, the main thread gathers all the results from the thread objects. It is then supposed to merge the smaller, now sorted, arrays into one large, sorted array.

I have currently solved this using a single threaded merge sort to nest the sorted arrays returned by the quicksorting threads together. Now the problem with this, since the merging does not happen concurrently, that sorting the in-file using a low number of threads (1-4) actually makes the program sort as fast as possible. If I up the number of threads a bit (say 15 threads), the program actually runs quite a bit slower than with fewer threads. To solve this, I wish to introduce concurrency to my merge sort/array nesting.

What I wish to do is: once two threads have finished quicksorting their parts of the in-file, a new thread will nest together these two parts, until every part of the in-file has been sorted.

Every bit of help is greatly appreciated, and I am thankful for example code and/or pseudocode. Thanks in advance! :)

---

Current code to sort the array:

```
public synchronized String[] sort(){
    String[] sortedWords = new String[words.length];
    SortingThread[] sts = new SortingThread[threads];

    for(int i = 0; i < threads; i++){
        sts[i] = new SortingThread(this, splitWords[i]);
    }

    for(SortingThread st : sts){
        st.start();
    }

    for(SortingThread st : sts){
        try {
            st.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

    indexes = new int[sts.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++){
        indexes[i] = 0;
    }


//This is where my merge-sorting currently starts.

    ArrayList<String> toAddTo = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(!allIndexesHaveBeenRead(sts)){
        String globalMinimum = null;
        int globalMinThread = -1;
        currentIteration: for (int i = 0; i < sts.length; i++) {
            String current;
            try{
                current = sts[i].sorted[indexes[i]];
            } catch(Exception e){
                continue currentIteration;
            }
            try{
                if(globalMinimum == null){
                    globalMinimum = current;
                    globalMinThread = i;
                }
                else if(current.compareTo(globalMinimum) < 0){
                    globalMinimum = current;
                    globalMinThread = i;
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e){
                continue;
            }
        }
        toAddTo.add(globalMinimum);
        indexes[globalMinThread]++;
    }

    sortedWords = toAddTo.toArray(sortedWords);

    int len = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedWords.length; i++) {
        if(sortedWords[i] != null){
            len++;
        }
    }

    String[] toReturn = new String[len];

    for (int i = 0; i < toReturn.length; i++) {
        toReturn[i] = sortedWords[i];
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: [Optimal parallel merging and sorting algorithms](http://www.lk.cs.ucla.edu/data/files/Huang/Optimal%20Parallel%20Merging%20and%20Sorting%20Algorithms.pdf)

Comment: Have you compared this with a purely sequential algorithm? Isn't the file read the most inefficient part of the process by far? What's the size of the array? How many processor cores do you have? Anyway, if you want help, you should post your code, in order for us to suggest improvements.

Comment: Thank you @JBNizet. The file I am attempting to sort holds 267000 words. A sequential algorithm would probably be better for a smaller file, but for a file this big, I have found that recursion+concurrency is the way to go. Code examples incoming (editing OP).

Comment: How many cores do you have?  Unless you have 16 cores, I would expect less threads to be faster.  I suggest trying the number of logical cpus or the number of cores you have as more than this is likely to have more overhead than benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem scenario is something like this

- A main thread needs N tasks to be done
- It spawns M threads from a Pool and works on the N tasks
- It waits till atleast one thread completes the task and does something with the result
- Continues to process the results till the time all of the N tasks are completed

CompletionService in Java 5,which does exactly what requirement is,

Here is solution for your problem statement,

```
 public class Sorter implements Callable<List<String>> {

    private List<String> data;

public Sorter(List<String> input) {
    data = input;
}

@Override
public List<String> call() throws Exception {
    Collections.sort(data);
    return data;
}

 }
```

And in main class,

```
  CompletionService service = new  ExecutorCompletionService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5));

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    String readline = null;
    Callable<List<String>> sorter = null;
    String[] words = null;
    int noOfRunningFutures = 0;

     while ((readline = br.readLine()) != null) {
        words = readline.split(" ");
        List<String> input = Arrays.asList(words);
        sorter = new Sorter(input);

        service.submit(sorter);

        // add them to the number of futures which I am creating - to keep track of the Queue length
        noOfRunningFutures ++;
    }


    while (noOfRunningFutures > 0) 
    {
        try {

            // this is a blocking call - whenever there is a worker which is already completed
            // then it is fetched from the Queue                 
            Future<List<String>> completed = service.take();
            noOfRunningFutures --;

            // get the value from computed from the Future
            List<String> sorted =  completed.get();

            result.addAll(sorted);

            Collections.sort(result);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I manage a fork-join project, TymeacDSE on SourceForge, that does exactly what you are looking for. It sorts the subsets and then merges groups of the subsets into one final array. Have a look [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tymeacdse/)